# eliminar repetidos en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un fichero en python con el siguiente contenido:

file.txt

```
http://www.alhondigalaunion.es
http://www.alhondigalaunion.es
http://www.unicagroup.es
http://www.jcarrion.es
http://www.jcarrion.es
http://www.aceiteslapedriza.com
http://www.vicasol.com
http://www.medgaz.com
http://www.medgaz.com
http://www.medgaz.com
```

como podria eliminar los repetidos en python trabajando directamente sobre el fichero sin borrarlo ?? estoy probando con set pero nada os dejo el coidigo:

```
 with open(file, 'r') as f2:
        for i in f2:
            array = set(f2)
            print(array)                   
            with open(file2, 'a+') as e:
                for a in array:
                    e.writelines(array[a]) + '\n')
```

Comment: Hola, has probado a poner ```e.writelines(a + '\n')``` una vez tienes el "array" no deberías tener repetidos, entonces en el segundo ```for``` no deberías acceder a array otra vez, simplemente utilizar sus valores en ```a``` (no olvides quitar los salto de línea al leer el fichero si no te saldrán repetidos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta que leas todas las líneas del fichero con `readlines()` y las guardes en un `set()`. Este tipo de datos no guarda duplicados, sino sólo una vez cada dato diferente. Después vuelcas el contenido del set a otro fichero (o al mismo, si quieres hacer el cambio "in-place"). El truco es convertir el set a cadena para poder volcarlo, lo que es sencillo vía `str.join()`.

Es decir:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f_in:
   unicos = set(f_in.readlines())
with open("output.txt", "w") as f_out:
   f_out.write("".join(unicos))
```

Comment: Hola amigo, como vuelco el contenido al mismo fichero?

Comment: @Daxtrox Basta poner el mismo nombre de fichero en el segundo `open()`